# MAX Group by ID

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm trying to select the MAX(QTYSOLDTHISDAY)by ID from an excel sheet. but the code below keep selecting many records with a MAX value. all I need is one record to be selected. I have tried group by ID, it didn't work. here is my code. thanks

```
Dept(0) = "01"
    Dept(1) = "02"
    Dept(2) = "03"
    Dept(3) = "04"
    Dept(4) = "05"
Dim DeptNum As String
Using cn As New OleDbConnection With {.ConnectionString = String.Format(ConnectionNoHeader6, FileName6)}
        Dim dt7 As New DataTable
        cn.Open()
        For Each DeptNum In Dept
            Dim cmd1 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(
                <Text>
                SELECT 
                    ID,
                        ARTNAME,
                            NETAMOUNTTHISDAY,
                            QTYSOLDTHISDAY,
                             AVAILABLESTOCK


                FROM [<%= SheetName6 %>$]
 WHERE ID = <%= DeptNum %>  and QTYSOLDTHISDAY=(select max(QTYSOLDTHISDAY) from [<%= SheetName6 %>$] where ID =  <%= DeptNum %>  group by ID)
</Text>.Value,
                    cn
            )
            dt7.Load(cmd1.ExecuteReader)
            For Each row As DataRow In dt7.Rows
            Next
            DataGridView2.DataSource = dt7
        Next DeptNum
    End Using
```

Comment: If your question is about the SQL, why is all of the VB.NET code included? Just post a small sample of your data, the results you'd like to get from that data, and the SQL you've written that isn't working as you expect. All of the other code (that isn't actually related to your question) is just clutter that makes your question harder to read.

Comment: Well the issue I'm having is with the Select statement.I'm able to pull all the records with the MAX but I only need one. And the reason I put the whole code because I have done a lot of research before hand and none them was related to what I'm working on. I tried posting just a picture of the excel sheet but the uploader won't recognize my PNG file!

Comment: I didn't say a *picture*. A simple text table will work with rows and columns of sample data and a text table of the results you'd like to get. The issue you're describing is with the `SELECT`, which is strictly SQL. It has absolutely nothing to do with all of the VB code you've  posted with it. As I said, it's clutter that makes it harder to read your question.

Answer (score 0):

Since excel is a Microsoft product, i'll assume that `Select top` is a valid statment.  Try adding a `Top 1` to your query.

```
SELECT  TOP 1
        ID,
        ARTNAME,
        NETAMOUNTTHISDAY,
        QTYSOLDTHISDAY,
        AVAILABLESTOCK

 FROM   [<%= SheetName6 %>$]
 WHERE  ID = <%= DeptNum %>  
         and QTYSOLDTHISDAY=(select max(QTYSOLDTHISDAY) 
                             from [<%= SheetName6 %>$] 
                             where ID =  <%= DeptNum %>  
                             group by ID)
```

If there are multiple records that have the same `QTYSOLDTHISDAY`, how do you decide which one to return?  If you need to make a decision like that, use an `Order By` on the outer query to get the record you need returned in the top spot in the results.

Answer (score 0):

I just spent half an hour searching for a language reference for SQL on Excel without success - to *verify* you could use `TOP n` like with SQL Server. Since others assume it works, I'll go along assuming.

Using `TOP 1`  you can *generally simplify your statement*:

```
SELECT TOP 1
       ID, ARTNAME, NETAMOUNTTHISDAY, QTYSOLDTHISDAY, AVAILABLESTOCK
FROM   [<%= SheetName6 %>$]
WHERE  ID = <%= DeptNum %>  
ORDER  BY QTYSOLDTHISDAY DESC
```

There is no point in a separate subquery to find the maximum `QTYSOLDTHISDAY`. Just order by it in descending order and pick the first row. That gives you an arbitrary pick from rows sharing the maximum `QTYSOLDTHISDAY`.

You can add more columns to `ORDER BY` to add one or more tie-breakers. For instqance, if you have multiple rows sharing the maximum `QTYSOLDTHISDAY` and you want the smallest `ID` among those:

```
ORDER  BY QTYSOLDTHISDAY DESC, ID
```

Comment: Top 1 defenitely did it, Thank you guys for your time.